Analysis of the electrocardiogram, finding the peak
Every time a peak occurs, I need to do a conditional count++. Give me ideas on how you would do it.
The first photo is an example of a graph.
enter image description here
Second photo is introductory information.
enter image description here
I tried to analyze the maximum points, but I ran into the problem that they happen all the time. Making the condition y>400 in advance is incorrect, because people are different =)

You need to look for points that stand alone, where the peak is dramatically higher than the points just before and after, or at least look for the huge negative-to-positive spike.

Scipy has a great function for that. (from scipy.signal import find_peaks), then use it: peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=10)

This is also worthy to try: peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, prominence=1)

@Tim Roberts
I tried to look for extreme points, they are throughout the entire chart. As for significant growth, this does not only happen in spades.

You should have a look to the find_peaks method as mentioned by @Nathan and this stackoverflow post.

I would try to identify local maxima in the dataset:

Define a window size (how many neighbour points of the current you want to consider)
Iterate for every point in the dataset.
If a point is higher than all the neighbours in the window then it's a peak.

I would try multiple window sizes, since you said people are different you don't want to get one that is too big.

The entire graph consists of local peaks. This makes the task much more difficult. Unfortunately, I don’t know how to post photos in comments.
https://imgur.com/a/fIYGFk5
